# How to prevent multiple payment charge

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.Net page which has process payment. Admin can process the payment. There can be multiple admins. If a page is open in 2 browsers and admin clicks Process payment, double payment is charged to customer.

I could do a check in my button click handler / controller method that we should not charge payment if it has been already charged once. However, that too doesn't prevent the problem entirely because if both of them click process payment at the same time it could again lead to issue. How can I solve this problem?

Should I be using lock / mutex. Please suggest what is the best way to solve this such that customers don't suffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some session management techniques to identify logins or I wish you are keeping a track of payment status in your DB.

- Now, add a column which accepts bit datatype.
- When you encounter the first transaction make that bit field to true.
- When you are encountering transactions check if the bit field is true or not. If
  it is true revert user with a custom message or booom update your DB
  and revert him with success message.

Answer (score 0):

You really should let the database handle the status change in a transactional manner. If you combine smart database processing with good business logic then the situation you describe will not arise.

Id' be inclined to a add a `ProcessingStatus` enum property to the payment status entity?

This could be:

```
public enum ProcessingStatus
{
    NotProcessed,
    Processing,
    FinishedProcessing
}
```

Avoid locking in your program, and instead rely on the database to handle concurrency.

So a high level overview of the controller/click-handler logic would be:

1. Start a database transaction (with serializable isolation level).
2. Retrieve the current status of the payment.
3. If `NotProcessed` then update the status to `Processing`.
4. Commit the transaction.
5. If 4 completes successfully proceed with the actual payment transaction.
6. If 4 did not complete successfully then roll back and let the user know with an appropriate message.

There is no need to lock in your program because the database transaction will ensure that only one person/process can change the status, and your business logic will prevent a duplicate payment going ahead.

As a further improvement, you could move this logic into a separate "service layer" (arguably, this kind of database/business logic should not reside in your controller).

Comment: Locking confuses me. I am still confused because page has query string. Let's say the ID is 1, the page should only lock this particular ID's . If another admin is viewing some other ID's data he should be able to process. lock keyword however is instance specific. I am not sure how to use that in Asp.Net webforms. Possibly I will have to use something more global because even static can't be used. Something like EventWaitHandle - would that help?

Comment: You should be locking the underlying entities to ensure that their states are atomic and consistent. Database transactions will ensure that data is consistent, if held in the database (which I would recommend). I think you should avoid any complex locking, and opt for a simple `lock` around any code where you read or update the processing status.

Comment: Basically, when processing payments you should *always* ensure that states are atomic. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing#Atomicity